# ¿Cómo puedo mover un objeto con jquery dentro de un div?

Tags: jquery

Hola muy buenas a todos.

Quería saber como puedo mover un objeto (como por ejemplo un div con forma de cuadrado) dentro de un div.

Los obstaculos los he creado a traves de constructores y jquery, pero a la hora de crear el personaje y hacer que se mueva de izq a dch y viceversa o saltar, no soy capaz :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy empezando con jquery y estoy un poco perdido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesante pero sólo con css y javascript te será bastante complejo podría decir, haz pensado en usar flash? bueno de todas formas te dejo un pequeño ejemplo "animate" de jQuery, espero que te sirva.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
    div {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #abc;
        left: 50px;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    
    <div class="block"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="parrafo"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).keydown(function(event){

        switch (event.which) {
            case 39:
                $(".block").animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "");
                break;
            case 37:
                $(".block").animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "");
            break;
        }
 });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: No es exactamente lo que quiero saber, ya que lo que necesito es que pusaldo determinados keycodes el cuadrado o personaje salte, se mueva a la izq o drch pero sin hacer clicks, pero aun asi muchas gracias

Comment: es lo mismo sólo que cambias de evento a "keypress"

Comment: Ya lo edité, ahora sólo es con las flechas izquierda o derecha.